# cmake unsuccessful with all static libraries needed in my project

Tags: c++, cmake

My cmake file is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(ICTSentiClfTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    ~/lyy/icttextminingplatform/include
)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/lib/libpthread.a
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libGolaxyTAP.a
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libWordSeg.a
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libwdselicense.a
    )

add_executable(ICTSentiClfTest src/NewSentiClassify.cpp)
```

I have all libs that cmake needs in the lib dir of my project, but in clion debug, it occurs undefined reference to XXX error:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ICTSentiClfTest
CMakeFiles/ICTSentiClfTest.dir/src/NewSentiClassify.cpp.o: In function `SentiClassifyAPI(char const*,golaxytap::common::AutoPtr<golaxytap::trainset::DocReader, golaxytap::common::SharedObj<golaxytap::trainset::DocReader> >)':
/home/yiyi/lyy/1/ICTSentiClfTest/src/NewSentiClassify.cpp:21: undefined reference to `Senti_Classifier_Init'
/home/yiyi/lyy/1/ICTSentiClfTest/src/NewSentiClassify.cpp:32: undefined reference to `Senti_Classify_Perform'
/home/yiyi/lyy/1/ICTSentiClfTest/src/NewSentiClassify.cpp:52: undefined reference to `Senti_Classifier_Exit'
CMakeFiles/ICTSentiClfTest.dir/src/NewSentiClassify.cpp.o: In function `CNNSentiClassifyAPI(char const*)':
/home/yiyi/lyy/1/ICTSentiClfTest/src/NewSentiClassify.cpp:60: undefined reference to `Senti_Classifier_Init'
......
```

The makefile I wrote:

```
all:./src/SentiClassify.cpp 
g++ -o NewSentiClassify ./src/NewSentiClassify.cpp -I/home/yiyi/lyy/icttextminingplatform/include -L./lib -lGolaxyTAP -L./lib -lWordSeg -L./lib -lwdselicense -L./usr/local/lib -lpthread

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Using makefile to compile does not encounter error.
Why? I googled that link_directories in cmakelist equals to -L in g++ and include_directories in cmakelist equals to -I in g++. It seems like my cmakelist file is correct and same with g++ compile orders.

Comment: Do not post images of code please.

Answer (score 1):

In your CMakeLists.txt file you should avoid absolute paths (especially since Clion will not necessarily launch cmake from your home directory).

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  <proper-path>/include
)
```

Also, you seem to mismatch LINK_DIRECTORIES and target_link_library. You should use below statements instead:

```
add_executable(ICTSentiClfTest src/NewSentiClassify.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ICTSentiClfTest
  pthread
  lib/libGolaxyTAP.a
  lib/libWordSeg.a
  lib/libwdselicense.a
)
```

Note that /usr/local/lib must be on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH by default (the path that the linker will looking at when doing the linkage). Also note that you should prefer target_include_directories instead of INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.

Comment: I changed link_directories to target_link_library and it occured error:`[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ICTSentiClfTest
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib/libGolaxyTAP.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib/libWordSeg.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib/libwdselicense.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/ICTSentiClfTest.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target 'ICTSentiClfTest' failed`

Comment: try this:  target_link_libraries(ICTSentiClfTest
  pthread
  GolaxyTAP
  WordSeg
  wdselicense
) . That is, remove "lib/lib" prefix and ".a" postfixes. Not sure where are these libraries however. Are they also located in /usr/local/lib? If so, you can simply link them as noted.

Comment: GolaxyTAP WordSeg wdselicense these three libraries are located in my project ICTSentiClfTest/lib dir. So now cmake can find pthread but can not find the other three libs.    `[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ICTSentiClfTest
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGolaxyTAP
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lWordSeg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwdselicense`

Comment: add location of these libraries using LINK_DIRECTORIES(<location>) before target_link_libraries